# Archive file is missing in organizer?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I am a beginner in I phone development.I have completed an application.Now i am thinking of creating an archive for submission . I am able to build successfully for archive and when i click archive in product it gives success message.But the archive file is missing in organizer.

I have include a latest bump api which comes with a warning

warning: (armv7) /Users/Desktop/Mobile/Myapp/Myapp/libBump.a(boss.pb-c.o) object file doesn't contain DWARF debug information

I am doubting whether archive file is not creating because of this error
If yes then how can i solve this problem.I have tried out giving both the architecture armv6 and armv7 then also it gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your project file and got to the target and open the Build Settings tab then change "Skip Install" to NO

[image]